# Laravel Data passed to View become a request

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have this annoying error in laravel where my HomeController passing a data to view changes it to an route request.

As you can see here, I am simply passing a string from my **HomeController@index** ...

```
public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        return view('home', ['char' => 'test']);
    }
```

then there would be a GET request at the console equivalent to the data.

[image: GET http://192.168.1.7/test 404 (Not Found)]

As you would have guessed, anything I pass here would trigger a GET request. Let's try passing an empty stdClass Object.

```
public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        return view('home', ['char' => new \stdClass()]);
    }
```

and the same thing happens.

[image: GET http://192.168.1.7/[object%20Object]]

I am passing BTW to a vue component and but displaying it directly in .blade.php doesn't cause this error.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
        <character-page :user="{{ json_encode($char) }}"/>
@endsection
```

You might say that it is probably the vue component making the GET request but no, I totally have no http request in my vue compo, it is just an innocent template-style-script component.

Comment: Please take a read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557

Comment: that's weird, can you check your character-page component again to see if there are no ajax call?

Comment: absolutely zero ajax, axios, href.

Comment: oh. what a stupid thing. It was the <img> :src attribute trying to access something non-existent on the `user` props. That's a deceiving error.